# Expected Value of Difference between Sequences of Independent Trials

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $X_{1}...X_{n}$ be i.i.d. random variables which admit a density $f$.

Let $Y_{n}=\min(X_{i},i=1,...,n)$ and let $Z_{n}$ be the number of r.v. $X_{i}$ which exceed $Y_{n}$ by more than 2.  How do I evaluate $E(Z_{n})?$.

Now assume that each $X_{i}$ have the uniform distribution on [0,4].  How do I find $\lim_{n \to \infty} E(Z_{n})?$.

Comment: There is nothing to "prove" here.  U may want to improve the question. Otherwise, it will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_{-i,n}=\min_{j\ne i}\{Y_j\}$. First, $Z_n=\sum_{i=1}^n1\{X_i>Y_n+2\}$. Taking expectations on both sides we get,

$$
\mathbb{E}Z_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}\{X_i>Y_n+2\} \\
=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}\{X_i>Y_n+2,X_i\le Y_{-i,n}\}+\mathbb{P}\{X_i>Y_n+2,X_i> Y_{-i,n}\} \\
=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}\{X_i>Y_{-i,n}+2\}=n\mathbb{P}\{X_1>Y_{-1,n}+2\},
$$

where the last equality follows by symmetry. Now,
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X_1>Y_{-1,n}+2\}=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{P}\{X_1>Y_{-1,n}+2\mid Y_{-1,n}\}\right] 
$$

and since $X_1$ is independent of $Y_{-1,n}$,

$$
\mathbb{P}\{X_1>Y_{-1,n}\mid Y_{-1,n}\}=g(Y_{-1,n}), 
$$

where $g(y)=\mathbb{P}\{X_1>y+2\}$. Consequently, since $f_{Y_{-1,n}}(y)=(n-1)f(y)\left(1-F(y)\right)^{n-2}$, where $F$ is the CDF of $X$,

$$
\mathbb{E}Z_n=n(n-1)\int g(y)f(y)(1-F(y))^{n-2}dy.  \quad(*)
$$

---

For $X_1\sim U[0,4]$, $g(y)=1-\frac{y+2}{4}$ for $0\le y\le 2$, and $0$, otherwise. Thus, using $(*)$, we get

$$
\mathbb{E}Z_n=n(n-1)\int_0^2 \left(1-\frac{y+2}{4}\right)\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{y}{4}\right)^{n-2}dy=\frac{n}{2}-1+\frac{1}{2^n}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be the CDF of the $X$'s and $F_n$ that of the $Y_n$'s. Then
$$
F_n(y)=P(Y_n<y)=1-P(Y_n>y)=1-P(X_1>y,\, \ldots Y_n\geq y)=1-(1-F(y))^n
$$
and the density of $Y_n$ is 
$$
f_n(y)= \frac{d}{dy}F_n(y)= n\,(1-F(y))^{n-1}\,f(y).
$$
You want to compute
$$
E(Z_n)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}E(Z_n|Y_n=y)\, f_n(y)\, dy
$$
where $E(Z_n|Y_n=y)$ is the expected number of $X_i$'s that are $>y+2$, i.e.
$$
E(Z_n|Y_n=y)
 =(n-1)\, \frac{P(X_i>y+2)}{P(X_i>y)}
 =(n-1)\, \frac{1-F(y+2)}{1-F(y)}
$$
(putting it all together yields a nasty long expression).

In the simpler case where the $X_i$'s are uniform on $[0,4]$, you get
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = 1/4\quad (0<x<4)\\
F(x) & = x/4\quad (0<x<4)\\
f_n(y) & = \frac{n}{4} \, (1-y/4)^{n-1}\quad (0<x<4)\\
E(Z_n|Y_n=y) & 
 =(n-1)\, \frac{1-(y+2)/4}{1-y/4}
 =(n-1)\, \frac{y-2}{y-4}\quad (0<x<4)\\
E(Z_n) & 
 = \int_0^2 (n-1)\, \frac{y-2}{y-4} \, \frac{n}{4}\,(1-y/4)^{n-1}\, dy
 = \frac{n}{2}-1+ \frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{align*}
Therefore (not surprisingly) $\lim_{n\to\infty} Z_n=\infty$.